# Spring MVC RESTful gives ClassNotFoundError for commons-logging while configured to run on GlassFish, works fine on Tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, glassfish, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am running a basic Spring MVC RESTful application with Glassfish 4. The servlet mapping from `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` to the RestController is correct.
Everything else is in place as well. Strangely everytime I run the app on Glassfish server, it runs into the error : `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`
Even when the apache-commons jar has been placed in the classpath.
From the stacktrace, I found out that `LogFactory` class is being referred from within DispatcherServlet. I even extracted the spring-webmvc jar and added commons-logging.jar in its classpath. But to no good.
I have tried all solutions available across various blogs/websites to replace commons-logging with a different logging framework. None of it worked until, I switched my runtime environment to point to a Tomcat 8 server. In the first attempt, It all came into place. I could see successfully run the RESTful app.

Any pointers/insights to this behaviour would be appreciated.

Comment: glassfish may have its own commons-logging library (probably newer one) in its classpath ( lib folder) . what version commons-logging are you using?

Comment: yeah i realised that while starting the glassfish server. Initially I had placed commons-logging 1.2, but it seems glassfish refers to commons-logging 1.0.4. For once, I removed all references assuming it would refer to the jar placed in glassfish library. It din't work then too, then i placed 1.0.4 version as well. Still no success.